# How add Text area field to Cart Page and pass data to checkout pages

Tags: magento-2.1, shopping-cart, custom-attributes

I want to add textarea to collect comment in cart page and then want to pass it data to checkout page and save it with order.
How can I do it and how to add and pass.

thanks,

Comment: not clear what you asking about